# primeng pKeyFilter makes the form invalid

Tags: angular, primeng

I have a field 'Aadhar' which is not mandatory. But it makes the form invalid even if i do not fill the data in Aadhar field.

```
<input class="input-field" formControlName="Aadhar" placeholder="Aadhar ID"
               maxlength='12' pKeyFilter="pint" pInputText>
```

Why it is making form invalid when it is an optional field ?

Comment: Because `Modi` Government telling `Aadhar` card is mandatory for every places. :p **Digital toilet**

Comment: hahahaha ! very funny